# Trying to make pandas python code shorter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to python and pandas. This code does exactly what I want it to do

```
dfmcomp=dfm.loc[dfm[ProgSel]=='C']
dfmcomp=dfmcomp[~dfmcomp.Code.isin(dfc.CourseCode)]
print(dfmcomp[['Code','Description']])
```

but I feel I should be able to do this in one line instead of three, and without creating an extra dataframe (dfmcomp). I'm trying to learn how to create better/neater code

I tried this to shorten it to two lines, by replacing dfmcomp in the second line with the code that created dfmcomp. I was hoping from there I could eliminate dfmcomp entirely and just print the sliced dfm, but it didn't work:

```
dfmcomp=dfm[~dfm.loc[dfm[ProgSel]=='C'].Code.isin(dfc.CourseCode)]
print(dfmcomp[['Code','Description']])
```

I got this error

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

And I am stuck where to go next. Can anyone help? Can this be done better?

Comment: `<scold>` Do not waste time on making code shorter.  If it works, and is fast enough, remember that READABLE code is vastly more important than TERSE code.  Most one-liners are unreadable and hence unmaintainable, `</scold>`

Comment: That's good general advice, but the OP might _need_ to do this for an assignment or the like, @Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this?

```
print(dfm.loc[dfm[ProgSel].eq('C') & ~dfc.Code.isin(dfc.CourseCode), ['Code','Description']]
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! Works a treat. I like this use of adding conditions, rather than stacking them which I was trying to do. I'll use this again

Answer (score 1):

Separating the condition into a mask might help:

```py
mask = (dfm[ProgSel]=='C') & (~dfm.Code.isin(dfc.CourseCode))
print(dfm.loc[mask, ['Code','Description']])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very readable

Answer (score 0):

```
dfmcomp = dfm[(dfm.ProgSel == 'C') & (~dfm.Code.isin(dfc.CourseCode))][['Code', 'Description']]

print(dfmcomp)
```